# How to use heading elements within a custom element?

Tags: accessibility, shadow-dom, custom-element, html-heading

Per [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/169) with the W3C html spec, using nested sections with multiple h1's is discouraged because no browsers implement the outline algorithm needed to make them work semantically.

However, if I have a custom element that needs to use a heading element, I haven't been able to find the recommended way for it to figure out what the heading level is where it's being upgraded/inserted into (so the element can determine which h1-h6 to use)

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@Heydon/managing-heading-levels-in-design-systems-18be9a746fa3) detailing some workarounds for the issue (that applies to components more generally), as well as one specific to React, but they all seemed a little clunky.

It seemed like this could be a common enough problem for there to be a recommended pattern on how to handle it (better than just passing/managing an attribute for it), but I don't know what that would be (I'm fairly new to web components)

Comment: Can you detail what the purpose is of the custom component? The way I see it, let’s say you have a Card component, and you’ll always use it in your `<main>` content, then you can pretty much count on using, say, an `<h2>` for its heading. I’m sure you are using it for something more complex, which causes your problem, I’m just saying that on most websites you’d avoid this by designing a proper document structure.

Comment: It came up as I was working on an example project to learn more about semantic html. I wanted to use web components to help modularize the content too (and learn more about how to use them). In my case I can (and did) hard-code the heading levels in each component, but it struck me as bad practice if I actually wanted the components I make to be re-usable elsewhere (like published to webcomponents.org or something similar)

Comment: Headings without levels, or relative heading levels are possible new additions to HTML
https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7390

Comment: True, though I'm not able to find any evidence of implementations of them (or active/published specs for that matter). And fwiw I think for now I've come to terms with having to manage this at the app level/interface between components (not ideal ofc)

Comment: The issue is even more relevant in CMSs, who’s main purpose is to manage and structure content, and even there they don’t care enough to simply pass a parameter ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534868/why-do-i-fail-ada-compliance-on-wordpress-headers-by-jumping-from-h1-to-h3/73191341#73191341

Comment: Thanks so much for starting this and sharing that great article. I care quite about this issue, but maybe we shouldn’t. Having headlines in a web application in the first place is already a big step forward, and maybe—just maybe—screen reader users aren’t as much put off by a messed up hierarchy in components as we’d like to think. I would love to know some insights from research.

Comment: No problem. And the 1 data point I've come across was from this podcast short episode - https://a11yrules.com/podcast/patrick-burke-talks-about-headings-and-screen-readers/ - which agrees with your hypothesis, though I think it was only in the context of iOS (and maybe Android too)